# No Printer Driver for HP 3510 in Lubuntu

Tags: lubuntu, printing, 14.04, hplip

Have just installed Lubuntu 14.04 and I am experimenting with it. The system finds my network printer, HP 3510, but suggests HP 3810 as driver. No other shows. That driver does not work. When I dealt with other Linux OS, there was HPLIP as driver and it worked like a charm. My Lubuntu is up to date. How do I make it access HPLIP as driver? It's not showing. When I go to download software, HPLIP is not even mentioned. Weird OS...

Comment: Try **`sudo apt-get install hplip`**. Its already installed (as standard) in **Ubuntu** 14.04 LTS, so the *package* is already availabe for ***trusty*** (14.04).

Answer (score 0):

I just downloaded and installed Lubuntu 14.04.  I also have an HP printer so I went to the HPLIP web site

http://hplipopensource.com/hplip-web/install/install/index.html

It walks you through the installation.  HP is one of the few printer companies that is really Linux friendly.